# Can't start Debian 10 on new ThinkPad T15g Gen 1

Tags: debian, nvidia, thinkpad

I've just received a ThinkPad T15g Gen 1 fresh from the factory. It has:

- Processor: Intel i7-10875H vPro (2,30 GHz, 8 cores)
- Graphics processor: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Super with Max-Q design (8 GB GDDR6 256) My goal is to have a dual boot with Windows (for gaming) and Linux (for everything else). So on Windows I go to the disk partition manager (type `diskmgmt.msc` on the Run dialogue launched with <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and create a large partition with free space ready for Linux to install there. Next in UEFI I disable:
- Secure Boot
- Windows UEFI Firmware Update
- OS optimizer defaults
- Intel TXT feature Then I install the latest Debian 10.9 (Buster) for the `amd64` architecture. The problems I describe below occur with either the default small installation image or with the larger DVD-1 image for the complete installation image. In the installation process I ask for Gnome and XFCE and `lightdm` as the display manager. However, when the installation is done and I ask to start the newly installed Debian OS, I end up with a blinking and solitary cursor in a blank screen. From there I cannot even get to a terminal as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>[1-12] keybindings don't work.

Next I shut down and on reboot I ask in `Grub` to go into `Recovery mode`. There I see the OS loading but it stops on a line saying `thunderbolt: control channel stopped'. For some reason, hitting`Enter`I am prompted to "give root password for maintenance". I oblige with the hope of updating (maybe some driver is missing?) but`apt update`returns`Could not resolve `deb.debian.org`. And yet, the laptop is connected to an ethernet cable and the installation process used the web without any problems whatsoever. The message repeats if I used other mirrors. So I don't know why Debian doesn't recognize the internet connection even though it is connected. Next as root I ask for the log of the booting process (`journalctl -xb`). I see two noticeable failures there because they're marked in red, one to do with `nouveau' and the other with`bluetooth`. I think the first one looks like the main culprit for failing to log in. In particular, it says something like this:

```
nouveau: detected PR support, will not use DSM
nouveau: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
nouveau: unknown  chipset (164000a1)
nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12
```

As for bluetooth, the log says something along these lines:

```
bluetooth hcio: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi failed with error -2
```

Finally, I try my luck with `startx`, which returns `Fatal server error: (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices (EE)` I think this is all folks!! As I said earlier, my main suspect is the Nvidia card and the `unknown chipset (164000a1)` that `nouveau` can't handle. I don't understand why it would matter though, because in the UEFI, in the option for `Graphics device`, the `hybrid graphics` option is on. So I understand that the integrated Intel graphic runs by default. The alternative is `Discrete graphics', which I understand to mean that the super Nvidia graphics takes over for every single graphic job. Any ideas or tips for handling this situation will be very much appreciated as I can't carry on with my work until I install Debian!!!!!! Help, please!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes it happens that the Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 card is supported only since kenrnel 5, whereas Debian Buster comes wiht kernel 4.19. Instead, Ubuntu 20.04 has kernel 5.4 and, hence, it works ouf of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You might get into issues with drivers and alike when trying Debian on relatively new hardware. 
Can you please try to install Ubuntu instead (which tends to have a better support for relatively new hardware in general)? Just download the Ubuntu ISO on say the Desktop on another Linux machine. 
Then insert your USB and use the `fdisk -l` command to locate your USB...next step would be to use the `dd` command to write our ISO to the USB:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/path/to/usb
```

and once this command is run successfully, try installing Ubuntu which belongs to the same family as Debian but with better support for relatively new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

in the BIOS settings you need to turn on <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys so they actually act as <kbd>F1</kbd>  <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> ... that fixed it for me for the blinking cursor and not being able to go to a console.

then I mostly followed [this guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/tp_p15_p17_debian_10.7_installation_v1.0.pdf)

I got my Thinkpad yesterday :)